# FormatNumber pattern with a space with Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am heading to use `FormatNumber pattern` with a **space** for a number. However, it didn't work with a separator of **" "**, it works very well with the separator of **","**. Please share me your idea or any feedback is appreciate.

Here is my code:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,###'});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

For the code above, it displays correctly, but I've changed **'#,###'** to **'# ###'**, it didn't work anymore.

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/huydq1903/FN36W/166/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way the number format pattern works. The comma acts as a placeholder for the grouping separator, and is substituted with the actual locale-dependent separator (e.g. `,` for English locales) when formatting the number.

To specify the grouping separator explicitly, you can pass the `groupingSymbol` option to the [`NumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) constructor. Unfortunately, that means you can no longer specify a pattern, because the documentation states that other options are ignored if a pattern is present. So, to get the desired result, you also need to pass the number of `fractionDigits` to the constructor:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  groupingSymbol: ' ',
  fractionDigits: 0
});
```

---

**Complete snippet**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Sales', 'Revenue Distribution'],
    ['Author', 56616],
    ['Company', 241444],
    ['Tax', 1343430],
    ['Payment Processors', 116666]
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ' ',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    pieSliceText: 'value'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```